# Dynamic SQL column names

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic

I have a query like:

```
SELECT [Week 1].Product, [Week 2].Product, [Week 3].Product, [Week 4].Product, Sum([Week 1].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 2].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 3].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 4].Transaction_Amount) 
FROM [Week 2],[Week 3],[Week 3],[Week 4];
```

I have data for 70 weeks name `[week 1]` to `[week 70]`

Is it possible to make `[week 1],[Week 2],[Week 3],[Week 4]` dynamic.

(i,e) have a master table where I can have 4 week names like `[Week 8], [Week 6], [Week 45], [Week 18]` and replace the `[Week 1], [Week 2], [Week 3], [Week 4]` with the above 4 in my query

IT IS AN MS ACCESS APPLICATION. Sorry I did not mention previously.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag.  The syntax is for SQL Server.

Comment: The answer to your question is "nope" (at least not easily).  This is a price that you pay when you store data in a denormalized format.

Comment: so you got table for each week... i would start to writing dynamic query to insert all weektables in one table with weeknumber...

Comment: If your query is in association with an application like php or dotntet etc, you can use application code to dynamically build your sql string.

Comment: @george How would I proceed to store data in a denormalized format? It is essential that I need to do it this way

Comment: @george: please delete the SQL Server tag

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Create some VBA code on a button which dynamically creates the select query. [How to build a dynamic query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304302)

---

You could:

1) Change your table structure so that you have a single Table for all weeks e.g. Week (ID, WeekNumber, column1, column2...). And then in your Select statement you can add a where clause to use a parameter to select which weeks you are interested in. This is dependant on all the weeks tables having the same structure.

2) Use Dynamic SQL to build your select statement and replace your table names. See [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: This structure wont work to create 4 columns as I have mentioned :(

Comment: It is an MS ACCESS application

Comment: sorry a mistake from my end.

Comment: ok. dont see why you can look at the 1st option above regardless of how many tables you have? Do all the tables have the same\similar columns?

Comment: I need different columns having different where conditions. the different where conditions is the problem. So I need dynamic input

Comment: So. I think the best direction is for you to create some VBA to build up your query and then fire it at your recordsource. See Updated answer for link

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using a dynamic query and then using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` to execute the query

The following will be a pseudo code which you can improvise as per your requirement.

```
DECLARE @STartCount, @TableCount, @Query, @SubQuery, @WeekTblName
SET @StartCount = 1
SELECT @TableCount = Count(*) FROM Master_Table 
WHILE(@StartCount <= @TableCount)
BEGIN
     SELECT @WeekTblName = Col_Name FROM Master_Table WHERE ID = @StartCount
     SET @SubQuery = @SubQuery + @WeekTblName + ' AS [Week ' + @STartCount + '], '

     SET @StartCount = @StartCount + 1
END

SET @SUBQUERY = LEFT(@SUBQUERY, LEN(@SUBQUERY) - 2);
SET @Query = 'SELECT [Week 1].Product, [Week 2].Product, [Week 3].Product, [Week 4].Product, Sum([Week 1].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 2].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 3].Transaction_Amount), Sum([Week 4].Transaction_Amount) 
FROM ' + @SubQuery

 EXEC(@Query)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am using MS access. So stored procedure is out

Comment: then why you tagged sql server.

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow. My mistake :( :( :(