# Choose group by attribute in query with MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query like this in MS Access 2007:

```
SELECT Year, Group, C, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Code = Table2.Code
GROUP BY Year, Group, C
```

What I would like to do is create a query (and then a Form) in which I can choose the attribute that in my example is "C". For example, I want to group always by "Year" and "Group" but change the "C" with D, E, F etc.
Is it possible and easy to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654066/dynamic-sql-column-names

Comment: Are attributes  `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` all of the same data type (e.g.`integer`)? Are they all of the same entity type (e.g. `company_id`, `group_company_id`, `director_company_id` are all of type `company_id` or perhaps `company_1`, `company_2`,`company_3`, etc)?

Comment: They are all answers to a questionnaire (e.g. question C, question D, question E ). Values are all text like "C.01", "C.02" etc. For example I want to group for the question C, and count all the values for the different answers.

Comment: I'm out: I personally don't think SQL is the correct tool.